# .NET Framework's FolderBrowserDialog is not DPIAware?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, highdpi

I've created a simple application with VisualStudio 2022, and .NET Framework 4.8. I have two monitors: A (100%, 96DPI), B (175%, 168DPI).

I did also defined *dpiAwareness* to *PerMonitorV2* in app.manifest.

I added only one control: *FolderBrowserDialog*:

[image]

And I have this code in form's click event handler:

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Folder browser looks great at first:

[image]

However, if I move it between the two monitors, it gets corrupted:

[image]

How can I make this system form also DPI-Aware?

Comment: If you want correct handling of high DPI you should probably switch to .NET 7. High DPI monitors were very rare when WinForms was created and by the time they became common, WinForms was considered obsolete, with WPF touted as the high-DPI future. Right now though, unless you want to switch to MAUI, WinForms on .NET Core has the best support out of all the stacks. WinForms and WPF are community supported and WPF doesn't have a lot of followers. WinRT, UWP were replaced by MAUI. And MAUI is very new.

Comment: For example, [Winforms got High DPI fixes in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-windows-forms-in-net-6-0/#high-dpi-and-scaling-fixes) and even more [in .NET 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/winforms-enhancements-in-dotnet-7/#high-dpi-and-scaling-improvements)

Comment: Or consider an alternative: https://github.com/Willy-Kimura/BetterFolderBrowser / https://github.com/ookii-dialogs/ookii-dialogs-winforms

Comment: May I ask why `.NET Framework 4.8`, insteaad of .net 5/6/7?

Comment: @RandRandom: .NET Framework is used due to an old codebase, which can't be migrated easily to .NET as of now.

Comment: `PerMonitorV2` DpiAwareness mode in .NET Framework 4.7.1+ is set in `app.config` only. `app.manifest` is used to specify what System versions are supported (mandatory for Windows 10+). If you have something (as you had before) related to DpiAwareness in `app.manifest`, remove it, since it overrides what's in `app.config` -- The FolderBrowser dialog is not exactly a WinForms object, the framework simply provides a wrapper for the System dialog

Answer (score 0):

Setting in application config is one thing.

But there are other things to be taken care.

- Declare compatibility with operating system.
- Also enabling visual styles. `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` should be called first in the entry point (your main function).

The below link has description about the above said settings.
In the below link look for **Configuring your Windows Forms app for high DPI support**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: That article talks about `PerMonitorV2` and the app.manifest, which the OP already used. WinForms on .NET Framework has known problems with High DPI and isn't getting any fixes. All interest is on Winforms on .NET Core now.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is one setting. But the OP should follow the other two settings also which I mentioned.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in the same link search for "Forms application, you must do the following:"

Comment: These are all defined, unfortunately.